# HttpClient calling API doesnt not pass cookie auth

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-authentication

Trying to call an API from a controller using HttpClient and the API does not recognize the user as authenticated and logged in. When calling the API from JS I have no issue. I noticed the HttpClient was only sending via HTTP 1.1 and so I upgraded to 2.0 settings the `DOTNET_SYSTEM_NET_HTTP_USESOCKETSHTTPHANDLER` flag but this made no difference. I have tried all combinations of the HttpClientHandler properties including UseCookies and the request is never authenticated.

```
        using (var handler = new HttpClientHandler {UseDefaultCredentials = true})
        {
            using (var httpClient = new HttpClient(handler))
            {
                var response = httpClient.GetStringAsync(new Uri($"https://localhost:64366/api/")).Result;
            }
        }
```

Will move to token based auth in the future but for now would like to understand why there is a difference between calling the API from C# vs JS. This is all HTTPS on localhost using asp net core 2.2.

Comment: Have you added the cookie somehow to the request in C#? Browsers attach cookies automatically to requests so that's the major difference.

Comment: thanks, I thought UseDefaultCredentials = true did this for me?

Comment: `UseDefaultCredentials` is always `true` by default, and that's only to use the credentials of the user running the application, which has nothing to do with the web application itself

Comment: That said, you need to take the current user's credentials and pass them on, depending on how the API authenticates

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Difference between JS and C# is that browsers attach cookies automatically to requests and you have to attach cookies manually in C# as *juunas* mentioned.

To obtain and use authentication cookie you may use the following pattern

```
CookieContainer cookies = new CookieContainer(); //this container saves cookies from responses and send them in requests
var handler = new HttpClientHandler
{
    CookieContainer = cookies
};

var client = new HttpClient(handler);

string authUrl = ""; //your auth url
string anyUrl = ""; //any url that requires you to be authenticated

var authContent = new FormUrlEncodedContent(
    new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> {
        new KeyValuePair<string, string>("login", "log_in"),
        new KeyValuePair<string, string>("password", "pass_word")
        }
    );

//cookies will be set on this request
HttpResponseMessage auth = await client.PostAsync(authUrl, authContent);
auth.EnsureSuccessStatusCode(); //retrieving result is not required but you will know if something goes wrong on authentication

//and here retrieved cookies will be used
string result = await client.GetStringAsync(anyUrl);
```

Comment: thanks - gave me the write direction. I had to populate the `CookieContainer` from the request cookies and it worked: foreach (var cookie in HttpContext.Request.Cookies)
      {
          cookies.Add(new Cookie(cookie.Key, cookie.Value, "/", "localhost"));
            }
      
            var clientHandler = new HttpClientHandler
      {
          CookieContainer = cookies
            };

      using (var httpClient = new HttpClient(clientHandler))
      { }